# NoReverseMatch error on password reset. The error only occurs on remote server and NOT on the local server

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-2.7, heroku

I am getting the following error when trying to reset a password. **The error occurs only on the remote server (i.e. heroku). I can change the password just fine in my local server.**

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'MTI', 'token': 'ak0pf1-d978cc8242a65cef3803f25c240c6996'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user_accounts/reset/(?P[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']

from urls.py

```js
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

What exactly could be causing this? If the problem is in the code then how come I can reset the password in my local environment. I am bit confused here, any help will be appreciated.

Could it have anything to do with the fact that I am sending emails throught SendGrid?

Answer (score 0):

The `uidb64` parameter is supposed to have between 1 and 13 chars, that's Ok.
The `token` parameter is between 1 and 20, but the one in your `post` request has 31.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why does it work locally and not remotely?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing under the hood. May i suggest you to use `path` instead of `url` in your `urlpatterns`? I find that to be waaaay more user friendly. Maybe it's just me hating regex though